# Make use of safe areas in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11

I am working to migrate my app so I can use it on iPhoneX without scaling.  Currently I layout a subview with the following code:

```
CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
frame.size.height = 295;
frame.origin.y = 20;
```

This works fine until you add in the notch.  I am not seeing a clear way to find out what the frame.origin.y should be set to, without just hard coding..  Which I would like to avoid.

What I would like to do is this - `frame.origin.y = 20 + self.view.safeAreaInserts.top`

But that doesn't do a thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `safeAreaInsets` is being changed after your code runs (for example if you're trying to perform layout in `viewDidLoad`). You need to override `safeAreaInsetsDidChange` to be notified when it changes.

Note that `safeAreaInsetsDidChange` is a method of `UIView`, not `UIViewController`, so you'll need to create and use a subclass of `UIView` to override the method. It would probably be sufficient to override it like this:

```
override func safeAreaInsetsDidChange() {
    super.safeAreaInsetsDidChange()
    setNeedsLayout()
}
```

And then you can set the subview's frame in `layoutSubviews`.

Or you could just use constraints instead of setting the frame directly, and let auto layout handle it all for you.

Comment: I am calling that code from viewWillAppear method - so maybe that's why it's 0?

Comment: Probably it's not set until your view has been added to the window's view hierarchy, and that happens after `viewWillAppear`. You should perform layout in a method that is specifically intended for performing layout: `UIViewController.viewWillLayoutSubviews`, `UIViewController.viewDidLayoutSubviews`, or `UIView.layoutSubviews`.

Comment: That was it - I will need to review my flow. but I think that works.  Thank you.